# How to fix sidebars using css-grids

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-grid, fixed

I would like to fix both the header and the sidebars positioned with css-grids. I tried to use position:fixed but it ends up messing up the interface. Is there a simple way to do this? Or is the only way relative positioning and height/width adjustments? I wouldn't want to make the use of css-grids pointless...

Here's the link to the Codepen if you find it easier (code without lipsum included below): https://codepen.io/fergos2/pen/MWgLqgL?editors=1100

Thanks in advance for helping this newbie!

```
<div class="container">
  <header class="header pd">Header</header>

    <div class="left-sidebar pd">
      <div class="box-1 pd">
        Box-1
      </div>
      <footer class="footer pd">
        Footer
      </footer>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content pd">
      Main content 
    </div>


    <div class="right-sidebar pd">
      <div class="box-2 pd">
        Box-2
      </div>
      <div class="box-3 pd">
        Box-3
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: #eee;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;

  grid-template-areas: "head head head"
                       "leftbar main rightbar";

  & > * {
    background-color: pink;
    color: #ggg;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
}

  .pd {
    padding: 15px;
  }

  .header {
    grid-area: head;
  }

  .left-sidebar {
    grid-area: leftbar;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;

    .box-1 {
      color: red;
      border: 1px solid purple;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .footer {
      color: green;
      border: 1px solid purple;
    }
  }

  .main-content {
    grid-area: main;
  }

  .right-sidebar {
    grid-area: rightbar;

     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: flex-start;

      .box-2 {
        color: red;
        border: 1px solid purple;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }

      .box-3 {
        color: green;
        border: 1px solid purple;
      }
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
```

seems to work for the header but not for the sidebars (even when setting top:200px for example). Any suggestions on what to do with the sidebars?

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/2dfso501/

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B. However, I'd rather have them fixed to the page instead of using overflow for the main-content.